# why shared_ptr can access with ingoring the "protected access right"

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I made some testing with shared_ptr,and i can't think out the matter below.I just started to learn the boost library. Is there anybody can tell me the reason?

```
#include <boost\shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class A 
{
public:  
    virtual void sing()
    {
        std::cout<<"A";
    }
protected:  virtual ~A() {};

};

class B : public A 
{
public:  
    virtual void sing() 
    {   
        std::cout << "B"; 
    }
    virtual ~B() {};
};


int foo()
{   
    boost::shared_ptr<A> pa(new B());
    pa->sing();

    delete static_cast<B*>(pa.get());

    delete pa.get(); //this line has a problem error C2248: “A::~A”: can't access protected memmber(declared in class“A")   
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

but it can be compiled when that line is commented out. Surely it doesn't mean that the shared_ptr will delete the pointer internally maintained out of the main function, just like what i did. Is there any difference between the pointer returned by `pa.get()` and the pointer internally maintained?

Comment: shared_ptr actually does something special about deletion, but your question does not illustrate that. Where in your code do you think shared_ptr is "ignoring the protected access right"?

Comment: I guess the O.P. assumed that `shared_ptr` was calling the destructor on the type `A` which is of course impossible because it's declared protected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that `delete` is called during destruction of the `shared_ptr` on the type of the pointer passed into the constructor. Have a look at the constructor here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#constructors

So when your `pa` goes out of scope, `B::~B( )` is called rather than the destructor of the type contained - `A::~A` ( which would be impossible because it's declared `protected`).

Comment: I disagree. The O.P. was confused as to how `shared_ptr` could access the protected destructor of a class it was declared with. The answer being that it uses the destructor of the type it gets constructed with.

Comment: The questions title reads `[...]access with ingoring the “protected access right”`. That should be a hint as to what the OP's real question was.

Comment: @dirkgently - The question is this: how come `shared_ptr<A>` destructor can delete the object when I can't call `delete` directly on the stored pointer?

Comment: I find the answer from here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#constructors        template<class Y> explicit shared_ptr(Y * p);         This constructor has been changed to a template in order to remember the actual pointer type passed. The destructor will call delete with the same pointer, complete with its original type, even when T does not have a virtual destructor, or is void.

Comment: Yep, that's the link I provided in the answer. You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it's a bit more complicated than that: the machinery behind `shared_ptr` is quite complicated.

First, let us prove there is no specific access rights granted to `shared_ptr`:

```
int main() {
    A* a = new B();
    std::shared_ptr<A> p(a); // expected-error
}
```

This will result in an error because the destructor of `A` is not accessible. Interestingly, the error occurs at the point of construction, which is a clue...

So, what is the magic behind `shared_ptr` ?

Internally, a `shared_ptr` keeps much more than a simple pointer and reference counts. A `shared_ptr` is built with a `deleter`, in charge of destructing the instance of the object. Where the design really shines is that this `deleter` is instantiated in the constructor and thus may know more type information than the bare `shared_ptr` type lets on.

A simplified demo:

```
template <typename T>
struct shared_holder {
    typedef void (*Disposer)(T*);

    explicit shared_holder_base(T* t, Disposer d): _ptr(t), _disposer(d) {}

    void dispose() { _disposer(_ptr); _ptr = 0; }

    T* _ptr;
    Disposer _disposer;
};

template <typename U, typename T>
void dispose(T* t) { delete static_cast<U*>(t); }

template <typename T>
class shared_ptr {
    typedef shared_holder<T> holder;
public:
    shared_ptr(): _holder(0), _ptr(0) {}

    template <typename U>
    explicit shared_ptr(U* u):
        _holder(new holder(u, dispose<U, T>)), _ptr(_holder->_ptr) {}

private:
    holder* _holder;
    T* _ptr;
};
```

The key insight is that the *disposer* is instantiated from the static type known by the constructor; this is why:

- `shared_ptr<A>(new B)` works
- `A* a = new B; shared_ptr<A>(a)` does not

You can read the Boost headers, the machinery behind the `shared_ptr` is quite interesting.

*As an exercise for the reader, why does `shared_ptr<T>` has a `_ptr` member ?*

Comment: +1 for including how `shared_ptr` remembers the actual passed-in type (on top of the template type)

Answer (score 1):

When you have:

```
boost::shared_ptr<A> pa(new B());
```

...you are calling `boost::shared_ptr` constructor and are dealing with TWO template parameters:

1. **shared_ptr template type `T`** (`A` in your case);

   `get()` returns `T*` so when you tried:

   ```
   delete pa.get();
   ```

   ...you tried to access `~A()` which is accessible only to `A`s children and therefore got an error.

   In the following line:

   ```
    delete static_cast<B*>(pa.get());
   ```

   ...you were downcasting `A*` to `B*` and called delete on `B*` thus invoking `~B()` to which you had access. (`~B()` is always calling `~A()` for `~A()` is declared as `virtual`)
2. **shared_ptr constructor argument template type `Y`** (`B` in your case) with the
   requirement that `Y*` must be convertible to `T*` (you can upcast
   `B*` to `A*` as `B` inherits `A` in your case).

   `~shared_ptr()` calls `delete` on `Y*` (`B*` in your case; `~B()` can access `~A()` and
   calls it) and this is what happens when `pa` goes out of scope (and this is how `shared_ptr` accessed base class protected destructor which was your original question).

`boost::shared_ptr` keeps internally a single pointer. When creating `boost::shared_ptr` you are passing to its constructor a **SINGLE** pointer which can be regarded as / converted to pointer to any of those **TWO** template argument types.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because the definition of the boost template declares the sharedpointer a friend of the <Class T> class from your template instantiation.

This is a snipet I copied from the boot shared pointer header file.

```
// Tasteless as this may seem, making all members public allows member templates
// to work in the absence of member template friends. (Matthew Langston)

#ifndef BOOST_NO_MEMBER_TEMPLATE_FRIENDS

private:

    template<class Y> friend class shared_ptr;
    template<class Y> friend class weak_ptr;


#endif
```

Comment: No, Boost couldn't make `shared_ptr` a friend of `T` even if it wanted to because that would require changing the definition of `T`.

Comment: This makes `shared_ptr<Y>` and `weak_ptr<Y>` friend of `shared_ptr<T>`